# How to insert text in a file after particular pattern in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have to insert some text after matching a pattern in between a line.

```
  core: [dev][delta3=deltafile;delta3dir=755|workpm][staging=stageingfile]

  Expected output is:

  core: [dev][delta3=deltafile;delta3dir=755|workpm][delta6=delta6file;delta6Dir=755|workpm][staging=stageingfile]
```

Now what I tried is below: But this is not working as expected

```
 sed -i 's/\<[delta3=deltafile;delta3dir=755|workpm]\>/& [delta6=delta6file;delta6Dir=755|workpm]/' file.txt
```

This is editing my file but [delta6...] entry gets appended abruptly after

```
File data is like: asdasdasdad   B-L-D-V-E-R

output is showing: asdadasdadd B-L-D-[delta6=delta6file;delta6Dir=755|workpm] -V-E-R
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `|` and the opening bracket `[` as these are special characters in regex.

Also, you use word boundary matching `\<` and `\>` which you don't need and might cause problems.

But still then for me it only works using `sed -E` (not sure yet why ...).

```
sed -Ei 's/\[delta3=deltafile;delta3dir=755\|workpm]/&[delta6=delta6file;delta6Dir=755|workpm]/' file.txt
```

or if your `sed` does not support `&` back-reference:

```
sed -Ei 's/(\[delta3=deltafile;delta3dir=755\|workpm])/\1[delta6=delta6file;delta6Dir=755|workpm]/' file.txt
```

Output:

```
$ echo "core: [dev][delta3=deltafile;delta3dir=755|workpm][staging=stageingfile]" \
| sed -E 's/\[delta3=deltafile;delta3dir=755\|workpm]/&[delta6=delta6file;delta6Dir=755|workpm]/'
core: [dev][delta3=deltafile;delta3dir=755|workpm][delta6=delta6file;delta6Dir=755|workpm][staging=stageingfile]
```

Comment: maybe someone can point me to why it's only working with `-E` ... without it, the `|workpm` is excluded from the match.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Issue was I was giving the pattern to match inside /\< pattern\>/

Comment: glad that it works now :-)

Comment: let's clean up the comments as they are not so useful for next users I think